# Installing on Giada MiniPC - blank desktop!

Tags: system-installation, desktop

The issue is as simple as that. I tried installing elementary OS on a Virtual Machine inside my Windows 8.1 installation and went "great"(meaning there was the usual Linux/VirtualBox issues but it installed and ran fine) so I made the move and created a bootable USB not with Rufus but with that other software suggested by Ubuntu itself, can't recall the name.

Well, I tried re-downloading the image and re-making the bootable USB already but it won't install on my Giada MiniPC for some reason... actually, it installs but **there's only the wallpaper after first boot**!

If I manually reboot it I get to the login and when I log there's the desktop alone again...tried having my Linux-savvy friend do something about it but it doesn't accept the common commands.

The cursor is there but there's really nothing at all aside from the desktop, why is that? The computer is this one: http://www.giadapc.com/products/minipc/slim%20series/i35B.html

**EDIT** I forgot to mention I thought about monitor/aspect ratio problems but I tried changing the monitor(I got a normal 22"something Fujitsu working great during installation) and even the cables from HDMI to VGA etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [blog post](http://youcantborrowmyrack.blogspot.de/2015/02/elementary-os-black-screen-and-blank.html) talking about your issue and it looks like - at least for them - it was possible to solve this with a boot option. I'm not exactly sure it will help you as well, but here is an answer how to set this boot option. If it does **not** work, just let me know and we'll figure this out in another way.

1. Boot up your computer to the blank desktop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. You will now see a terminal-based interface (black screen, white font).
2. Log in with your username and your password. When typing in your password, it will **not** be displayed in any way, so that's expected behavior, don't be irritated.
3. After the login, you run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (it will ask for your password again, because you are using `sudo`), which opens the texteditor `nano` to edit a file responsible for how GRUB (the bootloader) boots up your system. You can move the cursor of `nano` via the arrow keys.
4. Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add `nomodeset` as option. The line should look like this now: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.
5. To save and leave `nano` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> first, press enter to confirm the file name, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> afterwards to go back to the command line.
6. Run `sudo update-grub` now to update the settings you just have changed.
7. Run `sudo reboot` to reboot your system.

After the reboot, it *should* display your full desktop, including Wingpanel and Pantheon's dock. As said, if not, just let me know and we'll figure the issue out.

Comment: I'm testing this as soon as I get back to my office from launch, I'll update you and tell if it works or not. Meanwhile, thanks for clearing this up! I found that post but wasn't unsure how to operate!

Comment: if I press that combination of keys the computer freezes and I'm forced to reboot it :/

Comment: Mh, you said you are able to login, so what does happen when you press the keys *before* logging in? Otherwise, press and hold "Shift" during early boot, you will see the boot menu. Press "e" on the default entry, look for `quiet` (the line starts with `linux`) and replace it with `nomodeset`. Press "F10" and try to do the steps above again. If **that** helps, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Here I am! It all worked up until I changed "quiet" with "nomodeset". I pressed F10, it rebooted, I logged in and I tried to press Ctrl + Alt + F1 again and it **still** made my cursor disappear and blocked everything.

Mouse didn't work, keyboard didn't work and the light on the front panel of the MiniPC turned off. It was still on, but it's like it's freezing. Right now I'm downloading Ubuntu/Xubuntu to try and see if it's the computer or the distro.

Comment: Tried Ubuntu and it's so slow the desktop is not even responding but at least the UI is there, I'm trying Xubuntu now because I start fearing it's lack of hardware more than the distro's issues.

The non-appearing UI problem still says anyway.